# Ideal moment for saying Asher Yatzar

Tags: blessing, asher-yatzar

We have seen that even today, despite modern water closets, we should [avoid saying](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77807/15256) the blessing *Asher Yatzar* in the bathroom after relieving ourselves. We have also seen that we may have some [flexibility](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29333/15256) with the timing. Still, ideally when should be say the blessing? Right after leaving the bathroom while walking to the faucet? When pouring the water on our hands? After having poured water on our hands? How does it affect the timing if a sink is only available in the bathroom?

Comment: "Right after leaving the bathroom while walking to the faucet? When pouring the water on our hands?" how can you say a beracha if your hands are considering filthy after relieving yourself?

Comment: @robev This may be the first part of your answer!